# Change in one element effects other elements in that row

Tags: css, padding, margin, spacing

Assume the following code:

```css
*,
*:hover {
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

button {
  margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
}

button:hover {
  padding: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

How can I prevent the padding increase in one button to push buttons in the right-hand side if there is space?

Comment: You can define an absolute position for this buttons or store them in divs with a fixed size.

Comment: @CrynetOmega putting `position:absolute` completely hides buttons 1 and 2. I probably didn't get it right. For the other solution, do I put each of these in a different div? Do I put fixed size to div(s) or elements?

Comment: I would put each button in a single div, center it and define the div with a fixed width and height e.g.: `width:200px; height:50px;`

maybe another div with `display:inline-block;` around all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrease the `margin` and make sure the total is the same (`6%` in your case)

```css
*,
*:hover {
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

button {
  margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
}

button:hover {
  padding: 0% 2% 0% 2%;
  margin: 0% 4% 0% 4%;
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Is it because increasing padding and keeping the margin same in a box-like thing which is always the same size is technically impossible?

Comment: @LercDsgn which is logical because you are **adding** something so you need to also remove something else to keep the overal size the same (or we consider a complete different layout and there is a lot of ways in that case)